# Inverse image of $e^z$ is bounded for finite circle or not?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, entire-functions

I got struck on this option  of a question in my complex analysis quiz and couldn't correctly solve it.

So, I am asking for help here.

> Consider entire function $g(z)=e^z $ $ z\in \mathbb{C}$. Then is $g^{-1}${($z \in \mathbb{C}$; $|z|\leq R$)} bounded for every R>0 or not?

Answer is its not but I am getting that it will be bounded. CAn you please tell how to prove it's not bounded!!

Comment: If the negative real number $x$ is chosen large (as in large absolute value) enough, then $e^x$ is in the circle, so $x$ is in the preimage of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the answer is negative. If$$a\in g^{-1}\bigl(\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|\leqslant R\}\bigr),$$then$$(\forall n\in\Bbb Z):a+e^{2\pi in}\in g^{-1}\bigl(\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|\leqslant R\}\bigr)$$too, since $n\in\Bbb Z\implies e^a=e^{a+2\pi in}$. Therefore, $g^{-1}\bigl(\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|\leqslant R\}\bigr)$ is either empty or unbounded. And it is clearly non-empty.